# How to search reminders added to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

When I create a reminder in Google Calendar and then search for its description on the Google Calendar desktop webpage, nothing is shown. Only the "events" are shown.

It says:

> 0 result for ...
>
> No events matched your search.

Is it possible to search for the reminders?

Comment: This has been confirmed in the forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/wgJwqGqY48c;context-place=forum/calendar

Comment: 2021 and still not fixed.

Comment: You can upvote [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/10742241/ability-to-search-reminders-on-web) and [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/12879013/why-are-reminders-not-searchable) to help. Submitting a feedback can help too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This would seem to be an oversight on Google's part. Reminders don't appear to be searchable.

When you use the advanced search options, you can limit your search to a particular calendar (including "Other" calendars you've connected) or "All Calendars", but there's no option for "Reminders".

So it appears that there's currently no way to search for Reminders in Google Calendar.

As suggested at the Product Forum, you should use the "Feedback" tool to let the development team that this crucial bit of functionality is missing.

---

For what it's worth, if I search my calendar on my Android device, it *does* find Reminders. (It also works in *Inbox by Gmail* on my Android device.)

Comment: Google Calendar on the web unfortunately still can't find reminders, even after its [October 2017 refresh](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/time-refresh-introducing-new-look-and-features-google-calendar-web/). On a positive note, adding ale's comment about being able to find reminders with Google Calendar for Android, I should add that this is also true with Google Calendar for iOS.

Comment: @AlessandroVernet Wow, it's mid 2018 and this *still* isn't fixed.  How annoying considering I have literally *dozens* of reminders per week and almost no events, since reminders stick around until I actually dismiss them.  Good to know about Android, though.

Comment: Do you have a link to an open issue with Google?  I think it would be more effective and time efficient with one open issue starred by a lot of people rather than everybody going through all the hassle of reporting the issue separately multiple times.

Comment: going on to 2020, still not fixed

Comment: By this point I have come to treat Google's "feedback" tool as a way for you to communicate crucial information to Google which they can then ignore at their leisure.

Comment: It's Feb 2021. I still can't find my reminders in a browser. Trying "Send feedback" yields "403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know." The only workaround is using mobile app :(

Comment: Downvoting because other answer shows that you can search for reminders via a Google search for `search reminders [reminder text here]`

Answer (score 6):

I was able to search my reminders by searching Google for `search reminders [reminder text here]`. (While logged in under my Google account, of course.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in 2020, can anyone else still do this?

Comment: @sparrowt It works for me, just confirmed this (even when the [search term] was not in English).

Comment: This appears to search Google Now reminders which are not the same as Google Calendar reminders.

Comment: This found calendar reminders for me. I don't think Now reminders are separate

Comment: Tested and worked for me for searching my Google Calendar Reminders.

Comment: Working in 2021.

Comment: Did not work for me as of this comment's date.

Comment: Does not work for me in 2022

Answer (score 2):

Extending @ale's comment... A good place to see a list for two of Google's features, *Reminders* and *Saves* is in *Inbox* using the search **label:reminders** https://inbox.google.com/search/label%3Areminders?pli=1

Comment: Google inbox is no more, so this is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for reminders in Google Search. I often do this from the Omnibar in Chrome.

Use the search term: Search reminders for [your reminder]

The only problem with the reminders it returns in the results is it won't let you edit them, only delete them.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I exported my reminders via Google Takeout. Warning: the format is primitive. It's a simple HTML dump (not even XML), and dates are UNIX epoch.

Answer (score -1):

Google's calendar gradually deteriorates. It is now Oct 2018 and reminders are still not searchable. I found a limited workaround - display agenda (now called schedule) and search using browser's search function.
Of course it works only for whatever is displayed on the screen.