# Show missed reminders in Google Keep

Tags: google-keep

Is there a way to show reminders which have passed? I use them for due dates but can't see them in Reminders section after the reminder has expired. A query string I could put in search, perhaps?

Comment: update: I've switched back to Google Tasks which is more featureful in terms of tasks

Answer (score 2):

1. In the web UI at keep.google.com, click within the search box at the
   top.
2. Then select the "Reminders" button that appears.
3. At this point I see my expired Reminders, but I don't have any current
   Reminders.  You may need to search for or scroll down to find your
   expired reminders in Keep.

Comment: This isn't true as of 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Reminders are also visible in [Google Calendar](http://calendar.google.com) (assuming you've switched away from Google Tasks).

The easiest way to see them is probably with the "Agenda" view.

(Unfortunately, [Reminders don't seem to be searchable in the calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/94749/354) at the moment.)